# Nodejs: how to make intersection of two arrays of dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, intersection

How to do an intersection of matrices correctly. I'm working in nodejs and I'm trying to compare two arrays to get the same elements i.e. an "array intersection"

This is a pretty common question, actually, and even though I've searched and applied the resolutions you mention, I still don't understand why I can't. I have two arrays of dates, and the dates I'm handling are in the same format, so I'm ruling out the possibility that it won't work for that reason.

I used the most common solution, which was to use the filter() method to filter the array and validate via the include() method if array B includes any of the elements of array A.

Then try the same thing but with the some() method to check the array until it returns a true value.

In my case, what I am doing is through a range of dates, I generate a new array with the dates from the start to the end of the range.

The following code returns an array in "someDates" which is the result of trying to intercept the "currentWeek" array with the "holidaysDates" array

But I don't understand why it doesn't work?

```
function getArrayOfRangeDate(startDate, endDate) {

    let dates: any[] = [];
    let currentDate = startDate;

    while (currentDate <= endDate) {
        dates.push(new Date(currentDate));
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

    return dates;
}

            users.map(user => {

                let user_id = user.id;
                let username = user.username;
                let modality = user.modality.name;

                isHoliday.forEach((schedule: AttendanceSchedule) => {

                    let startDate1 = new Date(datestart);
                    let endDate1 = new Date(dateend);
                    let startDate2 = new Date(schedule.date_start);
                    let endDate2 = new Date(schedule.date_end);

                    const currentWeek: any[] = getArrayOfRangeDate(startDate1, endDate1);
                    const holidaysDates: any[] = getArrayOfRangeDate(startDate2, endDate2);

                    const results = currentWeek.filter(o1 => holidaysDates.some(o2 => o1 === o2));
                    // console.log('sameDates', results);

                    newListOfSchedule.push({
                        user_id: user_id,
                        username: username,
                        modality: modality,
                        currentWeek: currentWeek,
                        holidaysDates: holidaysDates,
                        sameDates: results
                    });

                });
```

**DEMO simple**

```js
const arrayA = [
"2022-12-19T00:00:00.000Z",
"2022-12-20T00:00:00.000Z",
"2022-12-21T00:00:00.000Z",
"2022-12-22T00:00:00.000Z",
"2022-12-23T00:00:00.000Z",
"2022-12-24T00:00:00.000Z",
"2022-12-25T00:00:00.000Z"
]

const arrayB = [
"2022-12-19T00:00:00.000Z",
"2022-12-20T00:00:00.000Z"
]

const results = arrayA.filter(o1 => arrayB.some(o2 => o1 === o2));

console.log('results', results)
```

In conclusion, what I want to do is go through array A and compare it to array B to return the elements that are the same in both arrays.

I leave you some links where they explain the interception of arrangements that I find interesting to share

- [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)
- [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing two Date *objects*. In your example snippet, you're comparing two *strings*. When comparing objects with `===`, you're actually comparing by *reference*. In other words, two objects are the same, *only if they are the same reference*:

```
const a = new Date();
const b = new Date();

a === b // false, different object references
a === a // true, exact same reference
```

So when comparing dates, you need to convert them to a primitive (like a string or number):

```
const results = currentWeek.filter(o1 => holidaysDates.some(o2 => o1.getTime() === o2.getTime()));
```

I've used `getTime` as an example which returns a number representing the date as the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

Comment: So, does it mean that comparing in the date format is not valid? I thought that if, when comparing as you say, I kept the same reference, with that alone the search could be done. I did not imagine that something as simple as this, thank you very much

Comment: You can compare dates however you'd like, but you can't compare date *objects* with `===` because that will be comparing them by *reference*, which isn't as useful.

Comment: @Izlia - A good read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/493018/294949.  I like this answer except for the implication that a string is just as good as a number for comparison.